# Dependency injection for testing a class

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, dependencies

I want to write tests for a singleton class `MySingleton`

*MySingletone.h:*

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject

@property (class, readonly, strong) Class_B* shared;

@end
```

*MySingleton.m:*

```
@interface MySingleton()
{
    SomeClass* _someClass;
}

@end

@implementation MySingletone

+ (MySingleton*)shared {
    static MySingleton* mySingleton;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        SomeClass* someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
        mySingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] initWithSomeClass:someClass];
    });

    return mySingleton;
}

- (instancetype)initWithSomeClass:(SomeClass*)someClass {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _someClass = someClass;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In the tests, I want to be able to substitute the concrete `SomeClass` with a fake one, so I defined a protocol that `SomeClass` should conform to:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol
@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>
@end

@interface MySingleton : NSObject
{
  id<SomeProtocol> _someClass;
}
@property (class, readonly, strong)MySingleton* shared;

- (instancetype)initWithSomeClass:(id<SomeProtocol>)someClass;
@end

@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton*)shared {

  static MySingleton* mySingleton;
  static dispatch_once_t predicate;

  dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
    SomeClass* someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    mySingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] initWithSomeClass:someClass];
  });

  return mySingleton;
}

- (instancetype)initWithSomeClass:(id<SomeProtocol>)someClass {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _someClass = someClass;
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

Now in my tests I define a fake class:

```
@interface someClassFake : NSObject <SomeProtocol>
@end
```

and initialising `MySingleton` with it:

```
SomeClassFake* someFakeClass = [[SomeClassFake alloc] init];
MySingletone* mySingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] initWithObject: someClassFake];
```

The only problem I left with is that in the test suit, although I'm not using the concrete `SomeClass` I am still dependent on it because it is being used in the `shared` getter and the linker will ask me to provide the implementation for it. What is the best design solution so that my test suit will not be dependent on `SomeClass`?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I came up with is to move the `shared` getter to a category:

*MySingletone+Shared.h:*

```
@interface MySingleton (Shared)
@property (class, readonly, strong)MySingleton* shared;
@end
```

*MySMySingletone+Shared.m:*

```
@implementation MySingleton (Shared)

+ (MySingleton*)shared {

  static MySingleton* mySingleton;
  static dispatch_once_t predicate;

  dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
    SomeClass* someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    mySingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] initWithSomeClass:someClass];
  });

  return mySingleton;
}
@end
```

And now, in the real code importing *MySingletone+Shared.h* instead of *MySingletone.h*